# Catboost: 'CatBoostRegressor' object has no attribute 'select_features'

Tags: python, catboost

I am trying to apply automated feature selection when training with catboost.
The catboost version I have (0.11.2) seems not to have the 'select_features' method advertised in https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_select_features.

AttributeError: 'CatBoostRegressor' object has no attribute 'select_features'

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade catboost`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the catboost version, I have checked the catboost changelog but couldn't find lowest supported version for this method. The documentation usually assumes you are using the latest version if not stated otherwise.